# CSS hover color not working

Tags: html, css

Using this code snippet:

```
#navigation li:hover > #navigation li a {
    color:white;
}
```

Hovering through a `li` element, the color of the text should turn white, but it doesn't. Can anybody help?

Comment: the selector is totally wrong my friend..

Answer (score 1):

You need to include HTML to get a more accurate answer, but i'm assuming this will fix it.

```
#navigation li:hover > a {
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need this:

```
#navigation li:hover > a {
```

Or

```
#navigation li > a:hover {
```

No need to rewrite the secuence again after the pseudo selector!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html this is a bit of a stab but my guess would be that you text is inside the a tag. Therefore you need to style the a rather than the li. E.g.

```
#navigation li:hover > a {
    color:white;
}
```

If you could post a link to the code that would be very useful though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in a wrong way.

**The solution depends on your current markup structure.**

Assuming the `<a>` element is nested in `<li>` elements, you select the link as follows:

```css
#navigation li:hover a {
    color:white;
}
```

If you want to select the first-level `<li>` elements in the navigation, you should use [children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) to do that:

```css
#navigation > li:hover a { /* select the li child the look for the anchors */
    color:white;
}
```

And finally, in order to select the child `<a>` element, you can use the following:

```css
#navigation li:hover > a { /* select li and look for the child anchors */
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something along the lines of

```
#navigation li a:hover {color: #fff;}
```

not suit your needs a little more?  Less code same output?